# Django: templatetags pass variable value

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I want to pass value of a variable from template to a templatetag but in the token list I get `picture.uri` as a string `[u'thumbnail', u'picture.uri']`

```
{% thumbnail picture.uri %}
```

Templatetag code:

```
from django.template import Library

register = Library()

@register.tag()
def thumbnail(parser, token):
    ...
    ...
```

How to pass variable value to a templatetag?

Sultan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very [well-documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag)

But I recommend to use some framework for creating tags, I use [this](https://github.com/vbmendes/django-meio-easytags).